# Linear Programming problem for finding supplier

Tags: r, optimization, linear-programming

I have a linear programming problem in front of me that I am searching to solve in R (any package). It seems like an unbalanced assignment problem to me with relaxed constraints on columns (repeated assignment is possible) or more general possibly a transportation problem:

I got 188 materials that I can get from 7 suppliers. Not all suppliers can provide all of the materials but each just some subset of the material demand.

What I know is

1. the demand for each of the material
2. how much I can order for the month at each supplier
3. which supplier can provide which material in which quantity.

One can imagine the sample problem as a table where the marginals are known, the x means that I can order at that supplier(s), the quantity could be split into smaller chunks, costs let us say are constant for all material/supplier combination e.g. 1 (or could be 33):

```
   Sup1  Sup2 Sup3  (Demand-Quantity of the material to get)
m1  x               0.12
m2  x    x          1.8
m3            x     1.9
m4       x          2.1
m5 x     x    x     0.1
   30    50   12
   (Capacity of suppliers 1 to 3)
```

Hence the problem is to minimise the order (cost) given I get all materials and not cross over the capacity of each suppliers. I need to get, given the demand, capacity constraints, a cost matrix and demand satisfaction matrix (which supplier provides which material), which quantities of each material to get at each supplier.

A concrete case, demand and capacity in tons (cost are constant for demonstration, all = 1):

```
demand <- c(10.994, 0.322, 0.046, 1.449, 0.253, 0.368, 5.221, 2.208, 0.989, 
            11.983, 0.046, 0.092, 0.115, 0.023, 1.633, 0.253, 0.276, 0.483, 
            0.966, 8.763, 0.276, 1.173, 17.963, 0.943, 4.232, 0.575, 23.138, 
            0.207, 10.465, 0.138, 0.92, 11.247, 6.486, 4.807, 16.606, 0.966, 
            4.554, 1.15, 0.644, 0.046, 0.046, 0.023, 0.989, 1.288, 0.966, 
            13.34, 5.796, 12.213, 10.097, 5.865, 5.704, 38.916, 7.291, 18.193, 
            0.184, 4.439, 58.305, 0.115, 1.38, 3.22, 8.234, 5.29, 2.369, 
            0.736, 2.668, 4.968, 3.496, 0.552, 0.598, 4.922, 0.322, 0.161, 
            0.483, 0.644, 0.736, 0.069, 0.644, 14.789, 3.243, 1.242, 3.381, 
            41.423, 0.644, 56.603, 3.841, 9.154, 0.23, 2.07, 40.871, 0.575, 
            0.276, 0.276, 4.255, 0.092, 0.253, 0.161, 0.115, 0.23, 0.092, 
            0.138, 0.874, 0.184, 0.483, 0.115, 0.161, 0.069, 0.184, 1.633, 
            0.184, 0.023, 0.621, 0.046, 0.184, 2.415, 4.301, 0.138, 0.667, 
            3.818, 0.138, 0.276, 0.023, 0.874, 1.702, 0.253, 0.299, 0.552, 
            7.153, 0.966, 1.702, 1.104, 0.713, 4.14, 0.575, 0.322, 0.115, 
            0.621, 1.932, 0.759, 0.69, 0.207, 0.759, 0.966, 0.023, 3.358, 
            1.357, 0.207, 1.242, 0.138, 1.265, 7.958, 0.529, 2.53, 0.552, 
            0.552, 0.046, 0.207, 0.069, 0.368, 0.092, 0.023, 0.966, 1.633, 
            3.151, 2.53, 9.2, 0.598, 0.138, 1.173, 0.345, 2.001, 0.506, 0.598, 
            1.104, 4.278, 0.345, 1.104, 0.253, 0.736, 0.138, 0.276, 4.761, 
            0.851, 2.622, 0.345, 0.92, 1.357, 0.092, 0.368)
n_demand <- length(demand)
capacity = c(55, 70, 60, 51, 10, 90, 10, 10, 10)
n_capacity <- length(capacity)
material_supplier_mat <- structure(c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(9L, 
188L))
```

I tried using `ompr` like follows

```
library(ompr)
library(ROI)
library(ROI.plugin.glpk)
library(ompr.roi)

model <- MIPModel() %>%
  add_variable(x[i], i = seq_len(n_demand), type = 'continuous') %>%
  add_variable(b[i], i = seq_len(n_demand), type = 'binary') %>%
  set_objective(sum_expr(x[i], i = seq_len(n_demand)), sense = 'min')

for (el in seq_len(n_demand)) {
  model %<>% 
    set_bounds(x[el], lb = demand[el]) 
}

for(el in seq_len(n_capacity)) {
  
  column_index <- which(material_supplier_mat[el, ] == 1L) # the sum of these columns/material quantities that need to be taken into consideration 
  cat("column_index:" , column_index, "\n")
  nr_columns <- sum(material_supplier_mat[el, ] == 1L) # for the constraint to allow up to 'nr_columns' to be tried to be taken into account7
  cat("nr_columns:" , nr_columns, rep.int("\n", 2L))
  
  model %<>%
    add_constraint(sum_expr(demand[i] * b[i]) <= capacity[el], i = column_index) %>%
    add_constraint(sum_expr(b[i]) <= nr_columns, i = column_index)
}

result <- model %>% 
  solve_model(with_ROI(solver = "glpk", verbose = TRUE))
```

But I don't think it is the right formulation and solution, at the end I was hoping to get the objective value as well as decision of the material quantities purchase for each supplier (for instance get m2 0.8t at S1 and 1.0t at S2).

Comment: Your R code for building the model contains coding errors/typos. For instance, in the fourth line you sum from 1 to `n` with `n` undefined. I suspect you mean `n_demand`. In the argument to "which", you reference a matrix `constr[]` which is undefined. To get a useful answer, please post corrected code.

Comment: Also, it is unclear what you are trying to accomplish here. The text of your question suggests you are trying to solve a transportation problem: assign quantities of each material demanded to each supplier, with (I'm guessing) not every supplier being able to supply every material. That would require a matrix of variables with dimension  `n_capacity * n_demand` (some of which would be forced to be zero because the supplier does not produce the material), you have one dimensional vectors of variables. Please try to explain the underlying problem more clearly.

Comment: Thanks for running the code, now it is without errors u mentioned earlier. I will try to restate the problem in order to get a better response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code now runs, but I'm fairly certain the model is wrong.

To get the values of `x` as a vector, you can execute `get_solution(result, x[i])[, "value"]`. To get it as a data frame (with columns for variable name, index and value), just use `get_solution(result, x[i])`. The same approach works for `b`. The expression `result$objective_value` will get you the optimal objective value.

For your model, the solution is trivial. Each `x[i]` is equal to `demand[i]` because you set that as a lower bound. Every `b[i]` is 0.

The description of your problem is a bit unclear (I have no idea what `b[]` represents), but you might want to have a look at the "transportation problem" (which applies to more things than just transportation of goods). An easy introduction is [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/operations-research-in-r-transportation-problem-1df59961b2ad).

Comment: Thnx for you contribution, however the transportation is in my opinion not the solution. You got an incomplete cost matrix, where just some of the relations demand-supply are defined. If u complement the not available demand-supply pairs with 0s, it´s a free ride to the destinaiton hence the lp solver will favor that. Even If u substitute the non-existing supply-demand pairs with a big number, than the solver will give results even for pairs that are not feasible. Hence, I think lp.transport is not the way to go. If all of the supply-demand pairs we defined, lp.transport would be the solution.

Comment: If the variables in the transportation problem are denoted $x_{ij}$, you just have to set $x_{ij}=0$ (either via explicit constraint or by setting the upper bound of $x_{ij}$ to 0) whenever pair $(i,j)$ is not allowed.

Comment: Yes that is right, I will upload the solution shortly. Thanks for helpfull coments. Please feel free to edit the answer with your R solution, if applicable.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you mentioned sounds like a variant of the lot-sizing problem in which there are multiple sources to produce one of the materials. Let's say, the variable $x_{i,s,t}$ represents the amount of material $i$ that is produced by supplier $s$ in period $t$. Also, the binary variable $y_{i,t}$ is being introduced to ensure that if any material $i$ will be started in the period $t$ is $1$, otherwise is $0$.

\begin{align}
\min&\quad Z=\sum_{i=1}^{I} \sum_{s=1}^{S} \sum_{t=1}^{T} c_{i,s,t}\cdot  x_{i,s,t}\\\text{s.t.}&\quad
\sum_{s=1}^{S} x_{i,s,t} \geq  \text{demand}_{i,t} \quad ,\forall i=1, \ldots, I, \forall t=1, \ldots, T & \text{(1)}\\&\quad
x_{i,s,t} \leq  y_{i,t}\cdot\text{lotsize}_{i} \quad ,\forall i=1, \ldots, I, \forall s=1, \ldots, S, \forall t=1, \ldots, T & \text{(2)}\\&\quad
\sum_{i=1}^{I} x_{i,s,t}\cdot a_{i,t} \leq  \text{cap}_{s} \quad ,\forall s=1, \ldots, S, \forall t=1, \ldots, T & \text{(3)}\\&\quad
x_{i,t,s} \in ℝ , y_{i,t} \in \{0,1\}
\end{align}

where, $c_{i,s,t}$ is corresponding order cost, $\text{demand}_{i,t}$ is demand of material $i$ in period $t$, $\text{lotsize}_{i}$ is the minimum lot/batch size that should be ordered, $a_{i,t}$ is the required capacity to produce materials and $\text{cap}_{s}$ is the capacity of supplier $s$. Indeed one can define a constraint $y_{i,t} \geq x_{i,s,t}/M$ to set a lower bound on the variable $y$.

Also, to extend the model into the standard material requirement planning (MRP), you can define some extra constraints to capture inventory level based on whose lead time.

Answer (score 2):

As @prubin corretly pointed out, the essential problem at hand is the transportation problem with some additional constraints on non-available quantities for relevant material-supplier pairs.

I could model the data using `ompr` as follows:

```
  model <- MIPModel() %>%
    # quantity to get from the suppliers
    add_variable(x[i, j], i = 1:n_capacity, j = 1:n_demand, type = 'continuous') %>%
    # objective function
    set_objective(sum_over(c[i, j] * x[i, j], i = 1:n_capacity, j = 1:n_demand), 'min') %>%
    # constraints
    add_constraint(sum_over(x[i, j], i = 1:n_capacity) >= demand[j], j = 1:n_demand) %>%
    add_constraint(sum_over(x[i, j], j = 1:n_demand) <= capacity[i], i = 1:n_capacity) %>%
    add_constraint(x[i, j] >= 0, i = 1:n_capacity, j = 1:n_demand)

  zero_constraint_on_quantity <- which(c == 0, arr.ind = TRUE)
  for(el in seq_len(NROW(zero_constraint_on_quantity))) {
    i_val <- zero_constraint_on_quantity[el, 'row']
    j_val <- zero_constraint_on_quantity[el, 'col']
    model %<>%
      add_constraint(x[i, j] == 0, i = i_val, j = j_val)
  }
```

where `c` is an aditional cost matrix, with cost for every material-supplier pair.

Additionaly, I find it interessting that an implementation of an elastic filter (out of scope for this question) can calculate over/under utilisation of the capacity, which is quite handy for further SCM planning.